# Scroll Behaviour Smooth Alternative for Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a site and want to use some anchor links. On all browsers other than Safari, the `scroll-behaviour: smooth;` works. I understand that this is not supported on Safari.

I have seen people mention:

```
import smoothscroll from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';
smoothscroll.polyfill();
```

However, I am not entirely sure how to implement it.

If someone can explain how to use this, or even a JS function that will give the smooth effect, it would be grately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Safari Doesn't support scroll-behaviour: smooth so we need some custom javascript to achieve the same effect.

```js
function SmoothVerticalScrolling(e, time, where) {
    var eTop = e.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var eAmt = eTop / 100;
    var curTime = 0;
    while (curTime <= time) {
        window.setTimeout(SVS_B, curTime, eAmt, where);
        curTime += time / 100;
    }
}

function SVS_B(eAmt, where) {
    if(where == "center" || where == "")
        window.scrollBy(0, eAmt / 2);
    if (where == "top")
        window.scrollBy(0, eAmt);
}
```

```js
SmoothVerticalScrolling(myelement, 275, "center");
```

Comment: Hiya, I have seen this example before, and have added an EventListener to one of my elements, to call this function. However, it does not work.

The div that I am trying to scroll to has ```class = mainTextBlock```, as well as ```id = "anchor"```, and I have tried replacing your example "myelement" with both the class and the id of the div, and neither seems to work.